# How to change variable when I slide on TabView in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, swiftui

I've following code for my TabView:

```
struct CardList: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach (0..<100 ){ item in
            CardViewNew()
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .padding(.vertical, 10)
    }
}
```

Every time when I slide to the next view of my TabView the following variable "i" should increased by 1 to show the next element of my array "shuffled_questions".

```
struct CardViewNew: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text(shuffled_questions[i])
    }
}
```

Would be nice I've someone can help me :)

Comment: where is “I” declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there's two ways to accomplish this. To answer your original question, you could use the `selection` binding of `TabView` to get a variable to change when the TabView moves:

```
@State private var tabSelection = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
            ForEach (0..<100 ){ item in
                Text("hi")
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .padding(.vertical, 10)
        Text("\(tabSelection)")
    }
```

However, it seems like in your case it seems like you may just want to pass the index from your `ForEach` as a parameter to your `CardViewNew`:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach (0..<100 ){ item in
                CardViewNew(index: item)
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .padding(.vertical, 10)
    }
}

struct CardViewNew: View {
    var index: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(shuffled_questions[index])
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to edit your `CardViewNew` so that it looks like the one I included with the line `var index: Int` in it

Comment: Well that error disappeared now. But there is one more at my CardViewNew-Preview: "Missing argument for parameter 'index' in call" `struct CardViewNew_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CardViewNew()
    }
}`

Comment: That's telling you that in your preview, you must also define an index. So, change that to `CardViewNew(index: 0)` for your preview. By the way, if you hover over that error, Xcode will probably even offer to fix it automatically for you.